# input treating integer value as string in python 3.3.2 shell

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python language. For this I am using Python 3.3.2 Shell. The problem I am facing is this:
When I type

```
    var = input("Enter number here")
```

It asks me for an input but even if I give an integer value as an input it gives me error

```
    TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

I don't face this problem in python 2.7 shell. Can anyone tell why?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect you're typing a few more things than you actually say. Please start a new python shell, and copy/paste the *entire* thing.

Comment: Python 3's `input()` is equivalent to Python 2's `raw_input()`, which does not evaluate the input string for you. You have to do it yourself using `int()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you need to know which type of input you will have, in case of number you should revise your code to the following:

```
 var = int(input("Enter number here"))
```